# How to get current date for timezone in javascripts

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, timezone

I have a pattern format of timezone as below "**2021-10-29T18:01:23+07:00**",
and so I want to get the current time with the same time zone as above, can someone help me with this problem,

I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
new Date().toGMTString()
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: [this maybe?](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/javascript/initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone/)

Answer (score 2):

In generall I would recommend looking into MomentsJS. It is very helpfull when working with Date. It comes with Format Functions and also with features where you can safely add or deduct Date.

MomentJS Docs: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

With native `Date` methods, the closest you can get is with use of:

```
new Date().toISOString() // '2021-11-02T13:12:26.229Z'
```

But this returns GTM time, to obtain local time in your specified pattern, you have to format it yourself:

```js
function formatDateString(date) {
    //Function to format numbers (prepending leading zero and adding sign)
    const f = (n, sign = false) => (sign ? (n < 0 ? "-" : "+") : "") + n.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping: false });

    //Compute Date, Time and Zone
    const d = `${date.getFullYear()}-${f(date.getMonth() + 1)}-${f(date.getDate())}`;
    const t = `${f(date.getHours())}:${f(date.getMinutes())}:${f(date.getSeconds())}`;
    const z = `${f(-date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60, true)}:00`;

    //Return it all together
    return `${d}T${t}${z}`;
}

var mydate = new Date();

console.log(mydate.toISOString());
console.log(formatDateString(mydate));
```

Or you can use 3rd party library like [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/).